# Need a PHP Regex for validation of mobile numbers and address fields

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression for validation the mobile number and address field, but input is from PSV file (pipe-sign separated values) i.e.

```
XXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$XXXXX$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$XXXXXXXX$|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX||
```

this input is converted in this format:

```
86082522|801213075672|NRIC|013333344444|SYED ZEESHAN||0107777777|0000000000|||||NO 3046|ROAD 12 MK.7$14000$,HEALE,PNG$PNG$||SHAID ABAD PAKPATAN|KALA|URB5467||8827|20151029|29/10/2015|28/12/2015|113.1000||BHALWAPUR RAWAPALNI KKOTA BANU|||
```

now this input is okay and valid but if some user forgot to add the mobile address field and address field than it should be not allowed to save in database, now im going to example of invalid mobile number field

```
86082522|801213075672|NRIC|013333344444|SYED ZEESHAN||8@#-777777|0000000000|||||NO 3046|ROAD 12 MK.7$14000$,HEALE,PNG$PNG$||SHAID ABAD PAKPATAN|KALA|URB5467||8827|20151029|29/10/2015|28/12/2015|113.1000||BHALWAPUR RAWAPALNI KKOTA BANU|||
```

now above example is invalid mobile number, because its containing the some charcters as well. so i need a regex that can remove these charcters.

Comment: What is a valid phone number/address? Explode on `|` to get each entry.

Comment: after 6th pipe sign it starting the mobile number field

Comment: You going to need to be more specific that that. I don't know what you expect a valid number to be. I also don't know what you mean the 6th field is the mobile number. What are the other fields? Is the mobile number always in 6th slot?

Comment: yes exactly its always stated in 6th slot, regex should read and ignore the first 6 pipes and than it should validate the input (mobile number. i.e always starts with 0 and having 10-15 digi length)

Comment: ignore the address validation, now i just need mobile number validation. input file is a psv file, same like csv file, but used pipe instead of commas. and mobile number will always come after 6th pipe sign, never before/after

Comment: One should never, ever, ever, ever try and validate an email address, phone number, or name using a regex. Although email addresses and phone numbers are standardised, the simple fact remains: **the great thing about standards is there's so many to choose from.** (just my 2 cents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay how about this.

```
$string = '86082522|801213075672|NRIC|013333344444|SYED ZEESHAN||0111123444443|0000000000|||||NO 3046|ROAD 12 MK.7$14000$,HEALE,PNG$PNG$||SHAID ABAD PAKPATAN|KALA|URB5467||8827|20151029|29/10/2015|28/12/2015|113.1000||BHALWAPUR RAWAPALNI KKOTA BANU|||';
$array = explode('|', $string);
if(preg_match('/^0\d{9,14}$/', $array[6])) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/iN5oT5/1

We require the string start with a `0` then have 9-14 (`{9,14}`) additional numbers (`\d`).

Comment: thank you this is what i need!! but can it also help to replace the or put the 0 in start if user forgot to add the 0 in starting? i.e. user input 111111111 and can we just add a 0 in starting as 0111111111?

Comment: The `0` can be made optional by adding a `?` after it. The `?` makes the preceding character optional. Was the 0 included in the 10-15 limit you previously specified?

Comment: @SyedZac success with that?